# Como agregar layouts programaticamente dentro de un RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Estoy creando un *chatbot* el cual te redirecciona a tal o cual actividad dependiendo la respuesta que le des mediante botones. El caso es que necesito poner las respuestas del *bot* en un `CardView` o `Layout` y eso mostrarlo dentro de un `RecyclerView`(para poder hacer un scroll). Entonces quiero saber como puedo hacer para que programáticamente agregue las respuestas.

Comment: Podrías agregar el código de lo que ya has intentado hacer, revisa la sección de [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para mejorar tu pregunta, saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

ya que no has puesto nada de codigo, la respuesta sera bien general, dentro del RecyclerView supongo que tienes algo como un LinearLayout, o puedes definir uno de la siguiente forma:

```
LinearLayout rootView = new LinearLayout(context);
rootView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
rootView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

Por ejemplo si quieres agregarle otro LinearLayout, lo puedes hacer asi

```
// aqui lo defines
LinearLayout linearLayout2 = new LinearLayout(context);
linearLayout2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearLayout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  

// y luego a agregamos como child del primer LinearLayout
rootView.addView(linearLayout2);
```

Esto aplica para todas los layouts, solo que algunos tienen diferentes propiedas, por ejemplo `LinearLayout.VERTICAL` no esta disponible en RelativeLayout

Saludos!